# Getting NameError: name 'video' is not defined in Vapoursynth/Python

Tags: python, vapoursynth

Trying to make a gif in vapoursynth, followed tutorials yet keep getting name error. If anyone could help explain what's wrong with it and how to fix it, I would appreciate it.

```
Failed to initialize script.
Failed to evaluate the script:
Python exception: name 'video' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\cython\vapoursynth.pyx", line 1927, in 
vapoursynth.vpy_evaluateScript
File "src\cython\vapoursynth.pyx", line 1928, in 
vapoursynth.vpy_evaluateScript
File "C:/Users/caitl/Pictures/bbh.vpy", line 12, in 
core.max_cache_size = 1000 #Use this command to limit the RAM usage. 1000 or 2000 is fine.
NameError: name 'video' is not defined
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nknyp.png)

```
import os
import vapoursynth as vs
import havsfunc as haf
import mvsfunc as mvs
import descale as descale
import muvsfunc as muvs
import resamplehq as rhq
import CSMOD as cs
import Dither as dither

core = vs.get_core()
video = core.std.Trim(video, a, b)
video = haf.QTGMC(video, Preset="Slower", TFF=True)
video = core.fmtc.resample(video, css="444")
video = descale.Debilinear(video, 629,354)
video = mvs.BM3D(video, sigma=8.84, radius1=1, profile1="fast", matrix="709")
video = hnw.FineSharp(video, sstr=1.13)
video = core.std.CropRel(video, left=72, top=52, right=107, bottom=52)
video = core.fmtc.bitdepth(video, bits=8)
video.set_output()
```

Comment: I’m sure the error message has more detail to it. Why aren’t you helping us know what line the error is on?

Comment: Because it says there's an error with every single line with video in it. 12-20

Comment: When you run the script you will get one error

Comment: Failed to initialize script.
Failed to evaluate the script:
Python exception: name 'video' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\cython\vapoursynth.pyx", line 1927, in vapoursynth.vpy_evaluateScript
File "src\cython\vapoursynth.pyx", line 1928, in vapoursynth.vpy_evaluateScript
File "C:/Users/caitl/Pictures", line 12, in 
#core.max_cache_size = 1000 #Use this command to limit the RAM usage. 1000 or 2000 is fine.
NameError: name 'video' is not defined

Comment: You should edit the question, but the error is telling you that when you use the name ‘video’ on line 12 of your script it is not defined. You pass it as a parameter but it doesn’t yet exist.

Comment: How would I fix it?

Comment: I don’t know. You need video to reference what I guess would be a video object. There’s probably documentation to tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define `video` before the call to `Trim` which takes it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The example script in [the documentation](http://www.vapoursynth.com/doc/gettingstarted.html#example-script) says you need to create a video object, for example, by loading a file:

```
from vapoursynth import core
video = core.ffms2.Source(source='Rule6.mkv')
```

This loads a video file `Rule6.mkv` using the [**`ffms2`**](https://github.com/FFMS/ffms2) plugin, which it assumes is installed correctly.

Comment: I know nothing about this library, and am only sharing what the documentation says.